# Wordpress attack flood

Tags: wordpress, apache, ddos

I have a few WP websites and they are being receiving a huge number of requests (about 20 thousand a minute) like:

```
www.example.com/adasd-asdasd-asdas-da/
www.example.com/fds-fdsf-dsfds-fds-f/
...
```

The problem is that it causes my db to check every time if the entry "adasd-asdasd-asdas-da" or "fds-fdsf-dsfds-fds-f" or ... exists in my db and it's consuming a lot of resources.

I've been reading hundreds of links in Google and all of them use ip/rate limit which is not a solution to me; I cannot use it. I've seen some blogs that when the user hits some wrong page they redirect the user to Google and by doing so they get rid of the attack. But how to they check every request in the database without shutting down the whole system?

It's really hard to solve this problem cause my legitimate URLs are like:

```
www.example.com/how-to-buy-a-flow
www.example.com/make-your-dad-happy
...
```

I have already 19 thousand posts, and every time a user sends a request like `www.example.com/fdsfds-fdsfs-dfds` I need to check it in the database to know if it exists.

I am already using CloudFlare which is doing a great job but I still cannot discover how to check if the request is not in the database in an easy way.

Comment: Just a suggestion and I don't if it is possible: create a kind of a cache on your server that gets automatically refreshed on a new post. Don't read anymore from your database, but only from the cache to see if the post exists.

Comment: @GuyT it's a good idea but cloudflare only caches my posts for 5 minutes, so if a user requests a post of 4 years ago I need to check in the database if it exists. I cannot only check the most recent ones cause users frequently browse over old posts.

Comment: And add them to a txt file? Don't know what IO request will consume? Ofcourse I mean the titles, so you get a list with titles and check if the requested post(title) exitst in the .txt file

Comment: wowww that's a much better solutino! You mean: I save all the titles in a text file (I will export about 19 thousands titles) and everytime a user comes in I check the strpos() if the title is present inside the txt file? Are you sure it's gonna be faster then using only mysql? I think that mysql is optimized to do that, do you think that moving it to php will help?

Comment: You've moved the problem from an (hopefully) indexed table scan to a full file scan. Use memcache and key the title so it's O(1)

Comment: @MikeB sorry but I did not understand what you said. What is O(1) ? Anyway, you believe it's not a good idea moving it from database to txt file?

Comment: Hehe, I already mentioned: it's only a suggestion, but if I see the answers it isn't probably a good one ;)

Comment: @Samul "In computer science, big O notation is used to classify algorithms by how they respond (e.g., in their processing time or working space requirements) to changes in input size" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @GuyT thanks for the suggestion I will certainly try it but I believe that checking inside a 1MB file everytime a users comes in will overload even more my webserver.

Comment: @MikeB thanks I did not know what Bid O was! It's really interesting. But do you believe that looking insde 1MB file everytime a user comes in is a good approach?

Comment: Mike B's the only real answer to this question. Move to memcache, since it puts everything in ram and will search faster. Anyway, at 20k/min I think that your web server will shut down before mysql does.

Answer (score 1):

You can block the attacker IP(s) with iptables or htaccess.

Comment: And if they spoof their IP? At the end the attacker wins, because you're blocking every IP/range.

Comment: They are using thousands of spoofed IPs. That's why I said in the question it's not a good solution

Comment: I see. In this case, I think it is worth to try Gerald Schneider's solution with fail2ban.

Comment: @Adam the problem with fail2ban it that every IP requests really few pages so it will not work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/). You can configure it to monitor your apache log for the resulting 404 errors and ban every IP that exceeds X 404 errors in N seconds automatically via iptables.

It's pretty easy to set up.

Comment: Thank you for helping but the IPs are fake. On the average every IP only requests 2 pages at every hour. So it will not help blocking every IP that requests 2 invalid pages at every hour.

Answer (score 0):

...or, as addition to the proposed above you can install the handy plugin [block-bad-queries](http://wordpress.org/plugins/block-bad-queries/)

Of course modifying the `.htaccess` and / or setting up `iptables` firewall is for advanced users and if you have full access to your web server environment.

Answer (score 0):

My company's WordPress site has also been the victim of several DDoS attacks. There are a few strategies that were invaluable to us:

- Using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) (monitoring /var/log/auth.log for SSH bruteforce)
- Blocking `/wp-login.php` and `/wp-admin.php` from unauthorized IP addresses using .htaccess
- Installing [Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) (Extremely valuable in protecting WordPress)
- Installing [Bad Behavior](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bad-behavior/) (for pingback attacks)